# How to prevent the text within the static control from getting clipped?

Tags: mfc

I am having a static control in which I am setting some text. When I am trying to set lengthy text in the static control the text is getting clipped.

Can anyone please let me know, how can I prevent the text from getting clipped.

Comment: What do you want it to do instead? wrap? show ellipses? expand the static?

Comment: @Alex K The width of static control is fixed and I cannot increase the width of the static control beyond that because I don't have space to increase on the dialog, but can increase the height .The text limit to be entered in the static control is of 255 characters.I want the entire text to be visible in the static control without getting clipped.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a static control always clips a word, that is longer than the width of the control. If you use the SS_LEFT style words are wrapped into the next line. So a higher control would help (I can read in the comments that this is possible).

But the Style must be SSLEFT and not SS_LEFTNOWRAP!

Another solution would be to use a Read Only Edit control without a border In this case you can scroll inside the edit control, because it is possible to give it the focus. Also you are able to use a vertical or horizontal scrollbar.

As long as you don't use WS_TABSTOP you will se no real difference between a read only edit control without a border and a static control. Except that the edit control can be activated with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Make the static text control larger than the text you a putting in it.  A window draws in its client and non-client space.  It clips to its window.

Comment: I am having a fixed length of the static control and I cannot increase the size of the static control, but  I want all the text to be displayed in the static control.Width is fixed and height can be varied.

Comment: You are not going to be able to get the text outside the bounds of the static text control  However, if you want something scrollable, I would just replace the static control with a read-only edit control.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about space on a dialog or form, or, language translation could be a possible issue, then you should consider using a [CStatic tool tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363079/add-tooltip-to-a-cstatic).  Using a tool tip would allow you to keep the current size for the control and provide a mechanism to display its full text.  When the user mouses over the CStatic, a tool tip pops up to display the entire text.  It's a compromise I've had to use to balance UI design with space on a dialog.